# How to add method to check email and password field data in Vuejs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

```js
< script >
  export default {
    data: () => ({
      email: "",
      password: "",
    }),
    methods: {
      validate() {
        if (this.email = "test" && this.password = "test") {
          this.$router.push('/Instructions');
        } else {
          this.$router.push('/');
        }



      },
    },
  }; <
/script>
```

```html
<template>
  <v-container>
    <div style="text-align: center;margin-bottom: 15px;">
      <img src="../assets/images/LogoGirmiti.png" />
    </div>
    <v-form>
      <v-row>
        <v-col offset-md="4">
          <v-text-field
            v-model="email"
            type="email"
            placeholder="E-mail"
            rounded
            filled
            required
            style="width:400px;"
          ></v-text-field>
        </v-col>
      </v-row>
      <v-row>
        <v-col offset-md="4">
          <v-text-field
            v-model="password"
            type="password"
            placeholder="Password"
            required
            rounded
            filled
            style="width:400px;"
          ></v-text-field>
        </v-col>
       
      </v-row>
      <v-row>
        <v-col style="text-align: center">
          <v-btn color="success" class="mr-4" @click="validate"> Login </v-btn>
        </v-col>
      </v-row>
    </v-form>

  </v-container>
</template>
```

How to validate email and password fields with some data. for example in email field after entering "test" and password "test" then only user should go to next page. else give some error message.

I don't know what's wrong with the below code, where without entering any data in fields, and click on button I am able to redirect to the next screen.

Comment: you're doing `=` you should do `if (this.email === "test" && this.password === "test") {`

Comment: Thanks. It's correct i missed that ===

Comment: Hello Riyaz. It is not good practice to check the credentials in the javascript code. For this case you can use libs which provide you to send users credentials to the server. and the server check the credentials. if they pass, the server send a token to the client. with this token the client make the next request to your api. For example JWT is a good solution.

Answer (score -1):

I think you're using `Vuetify`, isn't it? You could use the "rules" attribute for `v-text-field` tags.

Rules can be defined as an array of conditions which return `booleans`. See: rules documentation [here](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/forms/#rules).

Comment: The problem is actually due to using the assignment operator `=` rather than comparison `==` or `===`.